# How do i toggle UIButton using currentTitle in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

To the point, i have 10 button and i write a number in Title inside every button, that is 0 to 9. My problem in here is, how do i toggle a button function, just say when i press a number 0, the value will show in showLabel.text is 0 and the button is in selected state but when i push it again, the number is gone in showLabel.text and the button is change back to normal state. I using this below code but it can't solve my problem. I mean, just say i selected number "1, 5, 7, 8" and i want to deselect number 5, using below code my showLabel will replace all number to none not to be "1, 7, 8". So i think this is not good idea using this code.

```
-(IBAction)numberBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    if (button.selected)
    {
        number = sender.currentTitle;
        showLabel.text = [showLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:number];
    }
    else
    {
        showLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do that? Happy holiday.

Comment: Is it just me or `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;` is completely superfluous?

Answer (score 0):

Well. A think it will be good idea to make an array of 10 Boolean values and every time your button has been pressed - you just need to toggle corresponded value in your Boolean array and update your label using "for" loop:

```
for (int nn=0; nn<10; ++nn)  if (boolVals[nn])  [myString appendFormat @"%d ", nn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
- (IBAction)numberBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    if (sender.selected)
    {
        NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
        showLabel.text = [showLabel.text stringByAppendingString:number];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *newString;
        NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
        NSString *string = showLabel.text;
        for (int i = 0; i<string.length; ++i) {
            NSString *sub = [string substringWithRange:(NSRange){i, 1}];
            if ([sub isEqualToString:number]) {
                newString = [string substringToIndex:i];
                newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:[string substringFromIndex:i+1]];
            }
        }
        showLabel.text = newString;
    }
    [sender setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
```